# React-Native How to Call a function from addEvenListener defined outside componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, addeventlistener, back

I am trying to do something simple to program backbutton and got stuck.

I added the following event listener in `componentDidMount`:

```
  backPressed() {
    alert("Exit?");
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
        this.backPressed();
        return true;
    });


  };
```

I want this to call `backPressed()` function which will do various tasks. But when I call, it gives error

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.backPressed()')
```

Can't I call a function from within BackHandler? Any work around (other than putting the function within BackHandler)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. Instead of the above, I added this and it started working perfectly.

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
```